# attempt to index local 'on' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, helper

I can't see why this is giving me an error. I am starting on programming so it could be so embarrassing. It's a reusable button that's giving me a hard time. On line 12 where I try to change the on alpha ii gives me the error.

```
local Button = {}
Button.new = function(params)
local btn = display.newGroup()

local offIMG = params and params.off or "off.png"
local onIMG = params and params.on or "on.png"

local off = display.newImageRect("offIMG", 64, 70)
local on = display.newImageRect("onIMG", 100, 100)
on.alpha = 0

btn:insert(off)
btn:insert(on)

btn.x = params and params.x or 0
btn.y = params and params.y or 0

function btn:touch(e)
    if(e.phase=="began")then
        on.alpha = 1
        display.getCurrentStage():setfocus(self)
        self.hasFocus = true
    elseif (self.hasFocus) then
        if(e.phase=="ended")then
            on.alpha = 0
            display.getCurrentStage():setfocus(self)
            setfocus(nil)
        end
    end
end

btn:addEventListener("touch",btn)

return btn

end

local button1= Button.new()
button1.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
button1.y = display.contentHeight * 0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by line 12 you mean `on.alpha = 0` that means the problem is that the function call in the previous line `local on = display.newImageRect("onIMG", 100, 100)` is not returning a value as you expect and is instead returning `nil`. I suspect this is the case because you are passing the string `"onIMG"` as the first argument instead of passing the variable `onIMG` as the first argument as it seems you meant to do.

Try `local on = display.newImageRect(onIMG, 100, 100)` and a similar change for the `offIMG` line above that and see if that helps.